# Customvalidator control - SetFocusOnError="True" not working for CheckboxList

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am validating a checkbox list using custom validator and jquery to check required validation, its validating fine but its not getting focus on error.

the asp.net for CheckBoxList and CustomValidator is :

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblSellerCategories" 
 runat="server" 
 RepeatDirection="Horizontal"> 
</asp:CheckBoxList>


<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator2" 
 runat="server"
 ClientValidationFunction="CheckSellerCategory"
 CssClass="errorBox" 
 ErrorMessage="Select seller type" 
 SetFocusOnError="True"> 
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

and Jquery is

```
function CheckSellerCategory(sender, args) {
args.IsValid = false;
$("[id$='cblSellerCategories']").find(":checkbox").each(function () {
    if (jQuery(this).attr("checked")) {
        args.IsValid = true;
        return;
    }
});
}
```

How to get focus on error(if any check box is not selected). I tried with validation group as well but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `SetFocusOnError` is not working you could set the focus manually doing something like this

```
if (!args.IsValid)
   $("[id$='cblSellerCategories'] :checkbox:first").focus();
```

So your code would be

```
function CheckSellerCategory(sender, args) {
    args.IsValid = false;
    $("[id$='cblSellerCategories']").find(":checkbox").each(function () {
        if (jQuery(this).attr("checked")) {
            args.IsValid = true;
            return;
        }
    });
    if (!args.IsValid)
       $("[id$='cblSellerCategories'] :checkbox:first").focus();        
}
```